# multiple layer parallax scrolling content issue javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

I'm trying to get a parallax multiple-layer scroll-section in my website, but it seems like I have an issue with the javascript. This is the tutorial I am following: [How to make Multi-Layered Parallax Illustration with CSS & Javascript](https://medium.com/@PatrykZabielski/how-to-make-multi-layered-parallax-illustration-with-css-javascript-2b56883c3f27)

I want the exact same behaviour only as a Section below the header/hero. Here is the code I'm using:

```
 <section id="parallax-section">
        <div id="hero">
        <div class="layer-bg layer" data-depth='0.10' data-type='parallax'></div>
            <div class="layer-1 layer" data-depth='0.20' data-type='parallax'></div>
            <div class="layer-2 layer" data-depth='0.50' data-type='parallax'></div>
            <div class="layer-3 layer" data-depth='0.80' data-type='parallax'></div>
            <div class="layer-overlay layer" data-depth='0.85' data-type='parallaenter code herex'></div>
            <div class="layer-4 layer" data-depth='1.00' data-type='parallax'></div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

But it does't really work as it should, I think it has something to do with movement or offset, but I'm a total newbie

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {
    var depth, i, layer, layers, len, movement, topDistance, translate3d;
    topDistance = this.pageYOffset;
    layers = document.querySelectorAll("[data-type='parallax']");
    for (i = 0, len = layers.length; i < len; i++) {
      layer = layers[i];
      depth = layer.getAttribute('data-depth');
      movement = -(topDistance * depth);
      translate3d = 'translate3d(0, ' + movement + 'px, 0)';
      layer.style['-webkit-transform'] = translate3d;
      layer.style['-moz-transform'] = translate3d;
      layer.style['-ms-transform'] = translate3d;
      layer.style['-o-transform'] = translate3d;
      layer.style.transform = translate3d;
    }
  });

}).call(this);
```

I already tried to put it on the top as Hero, no Problem. Here's a screenshot.

[image: Here's a screenshot]

I'd really appreciate if there's anybody out there who can help.